# Particular type of Paragraph

Tags: paragraphs

Is there a way to obtain a paragraph that have in output just

```
    \underline{\emph{Esempio.}}
```

i.e.

[image]

i.e. without ''`\textbf`'' the word.

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you want. `\underline{\emph{Esempio.}}` does not output boldface text, to see that you can type `\underline{\textbf{\emph{Esempio.}}}` and compare the results (they are quite different).

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos As a mattere of fact  '' paragraph '' boldface the text.. I need a kind of paragraph-command that have as output the image in the question.

Comment: That completely depends on the class you are using, since you did not provide a MWE I have no way of knowing what it is that you're doing and what you want. Nevertheless, `titlesec` seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Please, add information about the class you're using. Note, though, that underlining is not a recommended typographic device; italics already gives emphasis, “double emphasis” is not necessary.

Comment: I use: 
        \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{extbook}
..

Comment: @AndreaLeo There's the [edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/334973/edit) buttom below you're question, you can use it to modify the question and add useful Information at any time. Also, to Format "text" as code put the text between `` then it looks like "`text`".

Comment: You're welcome, but **don't forget** that the **best way** of  saying thank's in TeX.SE is to **upvote** questions and answers that are helpful. And, of course, **accept** a correct answer (when there is one). `:D`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I firmly agree with @egreg: underline emphasized text is too much Information, a MWE with the class you're using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{extbook}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{titlesec,blindtext}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{}
\newcommand{\tmp}[1]{}
\let\tmp\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\tmp{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ulemparagraph}[1]{\tmp{\uline{\emph{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
Section text

\ulemparagraph{Some other text}

\paragraph{Even more text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is a problem. Now all paragraphs are modified. I need an additional command in order to obtain what I want. Thank you.

Comment: Ok I get it. However `\uline` probably is one of yours definition.

Comment: I thought that was what you wanted to do. Do you wish to have both commands: a `\paragraph` (which is bold) and a `\ulemparagraph` (which would be underlined and emphasized)?. BTW, `\uline` is defined by `ulem` package which allows linebreaks amongst other features.

Comment: Ok. How we define `\ulemparagraph` and hold also `\paragraph`?

Comment: If you look closely, you'll see that there's no `\paragraph` command, I made `\tmp` inherit `\paragraph`'s definition. So we just make a new command with `\tmp` which makes the text bold. See edited answer! `=D`

Comment: That's what I want! Thank you so much! <3

Comment: are you sure that the command `\paraghraph` is not changed? Because I have some kind of troubles... In other types of paragraph that I have defined now there is a `*` before the paragraph..

Comment: The command has changed, yes. But ir was not supposed to have that kind of behavior. But if you don't mind me asking: what are you using this command for?? It is actually supposed to be a document division, like `\section`, so it's not to be used to make properly said, "paragraphs"...